# How to get the Button & ImageButton controls using Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

When finding a control that caused the postback, `<asp:ImageButton>` & `<asp:Button>`  are exceptions as they do not use `__doPostBack` function. This fact is also supported by [**`this Article`**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-find-the-control-that-caused-PostBack-in-ASP.Net.aspx).

So, as the article pointed above uses a hiddenField, Javascript codes for workaround, Is there a more elegant way of doing this??

What I want is when using a Button/ImageButton control, i still want to use `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` to somehow get the control name. Is there any setting that i need to know??

OR

Any property of Button / ImageButton that will make it use the `__doPostBack` function ??

Below is code I was trying ::

### EventTargets.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="EventTargets.aspx.cs" Inherits="EventTargets" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"
     ClientIDMode="Static"/>
</asp:Content>
```

And the complete code of my cs file:

### EventTargets.aspx.cs

```
public partial class EventTargets: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string CtrlID = string.Empty;
            // for Button Controls, this is always string.Empty
            // and therefore it doesn't goes inside IF statement
            if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null &&
                Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != string.Empty)
            {
                CtrlID = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can force `Button` control to use javascript for submitting to server by setting `UseSubmitBehavior` property of `Button` control to `false`. This way you'll have `__EVENTTARGET` value in code-behind. But this won't work for `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know its ELEGANT WAY for you or not :) but it is easy..see..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Control c = GetPostBackControl(this.Page);

        string ctrlId = c.ID;
    }
}

 private Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
    Control control = null;

    string postBackControlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");

    string eventArgument = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
    if (postBackControlName != null && postBackControlName.Length > 0)
    {
        control = Page.FindControl(postBackControlName);
    }

    else
    {
        foreach (string str in Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = Page.FindControl(str);
            if (c is Button)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return control;
}
```